# Noname Bluetooth 5.0 dongle to connect BT mouse

Tags: keyboard, mouse, bluetooth, adapter, wireless-mouse

I see there are a lot of cheap noname Bluetooth 4.0/5.0 USB Dongles marked as "Music" or "Audio" connect device on [Aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000624837974.htm).

Can I use such adapters to connect Bluetooth mouse/keyboard?
Or they are really only audio specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compatibility depends on the bluetooth profiles that the dongle and your peripherals support. The required profile might not be implemented or enabled on the dongle marketed as an "audio" receiver. If your mouse expects an HID signal, but the dongle can only send/receive A2DP, you won't be able to make a connection.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles

There are, however, universal receivers that you can plug into, for example, a PC without a bluetooth chip, and connect to a variety of devices.

With [something like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0775YF36R) you'd be paying under 10 USD and it would definitely work.